# Capitalization after a quotation mark (conversation)

Tags: quotations

I read a story written by Beatrix Potter, "The Tailor of Gloucester."

*He cut his coats without waste, according to his embroidered cloth; they were very small ends and snippets that lay about upon the table—"Too narrow breadths for nought—except waistcoats for mice," said the tailor.*

I am a little confused about the rules.  Here, "said the tailor." is not capitalized, and there is also inversion here.

*Now all day long while the tailor was out at work, Simpkin kept house by himself; and he also was fond of the mice, though he gave them no satin for coats!
"Miaw?" said the cat when the tailor opened the door. "Miaw?"*

Here is also "said the cat," a non-capitalized phrase.

How can I quote conversations when I don't use inversion?

1. "I have a question," she said.
2. "I have a question." She said.
3. "How is your life in Vancouver?" She said.
4. "How is your life in Vancouver?" she said.
5. "I have a question," she said, "how is your life in Vancouver?"
6. －"Too narrow breadths for nought—except waistcoats for mice!" The tailor said.

Comment: Why do you see inversion as being a factor here?

Comment: @tkp I thought that would make the phrase "said the tailor" the part of the whole sentence.  Actually, I don't understand well why there is inversion

Comment: Sorry @Nigutumok, but I still don't understand your question. You seem to be having a difficulty in how to quote a piece of writing that is (or contains) direct speech. Is that correct? If so, exactly what exactly is the difficulty? What is it about quoting text that contains direct speech that is more difficult than quoting text that does *not* contain direct speech? Is it that you have been told that inversion is needed?

Comment: Oops, I was editing my comment to make it clearer but it was past the 5 minutes allowed for editing. so I deleted it and added it back, hence it now being after your reply to it! (Which it now looks like you have deleted! )

Comment: @tkp Me, too!  Yes, I have difficulty in that.  I am not sure which I can use and which I cannot use from #1 to #6.  I thought if it was not a conversation, I can easily judge where I should separate the words as sentences. I would like to know the way how I can quote without inversion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They aren't supposed to be capitalized after a quotation. This is because it is part of the sentence, only separate sentences require the capitalization.

Comment: Yes, a quoted sentence within a sentence does not end the outer sentence.